# Limit asp.net request execution time

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis

I have ASP.NET 4 handler that must response less than 50 ms. In some situations, e.g call to remote services, it hang for longer time.

Is it possible to kill (maybe in IIS) such requests longer than 50 ms?

There are about 1000 requests per seccond, if I wrap every request in separate task with timeout then iis worker process queue increase extremly fast and hung all system. It happens after iisrestart or when we have a lot of timeouts to remote services.

**UPD:** This is API handler that handles requests from other services (servers)

**UPD2:** I have tryed wrap request in separate task with timeout, but in doesn't work when there are many requests per second. It's too expensive to create separate task even with threadpool

TimeoutFunctionWrapper:

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func, int timeout)
{
    object sync = new object();
    bool isCompleted = false;

    WaitCallback watcher = obj => {
        Thread watchedThread = obj as Thread;

        lock (sync)
        {
            if (!isCompleted)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(sync, timeout);
            }
        }

        if (!isCompleted)
        {
            watchedThread.Abort();
        }
    };

    try
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(watcher, Thread.CurrentThread);
        return func();
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        // This is our own exception.
        Thread.ResetAbort();
        return default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            isCompleted = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(sync);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement your own timeout mechanism. Start a timer and cancel all outstanding work after 50ms.

[Cancellation must be cooperative in .NET.](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com%20cooperative%20cancellation%20.net) There is no other realistic way to cancel work.

Requests to external services can be cancelled. How to do this depends on the specific API you are using.

Comment: More importantly, if the 50ms is really important, then the timeout should be done on the client side. It would be possible for the server to time out, then either not respond to the client for a second, or the error response could take a second to get to the client.

Comment: This is API handler that handles requests from other services (servers)

Comment: I have tryed wrap request in separate task with timeout, but in doesn't work when there are many requests per second. It's too expensive to create separate task even with threadpool

Comment: @AlexanderKarpinskiy hard to say what went wrong without knowing what you did.

Comment: @usr I've updated question with TimeoutWrapper example

Comment: Cancellation must be cooperative on .NET. You are uncooperatively aborting threads. Google "Thread.Abort evil". Use the CancellationToken API to create a token that is cancelled after 50ms. Pass that token around to everything that must be cancellable.

Comment: @usr I have some "black box" method that call remote services, and I can't invoke CancellationToken into them. What do you recommend in such situation?

Comment: @AlexanderKarpinskiy cancel the web service invocation. The remote server will continue processing but its response will be thrown away and your code continues immediately.